# Run Perl Script on Apache2/Redhat5.5

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, perl

I am working with an Apache2/Redhat5.5 configuration. I am trying to configure (and learn) how to run Perl scripts which is new to me.

In my httpd.conf file I made these changes and/or notice these settings:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.cgi index.pl
...
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
...
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
...
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have placed this script: http://www.seaglass.com/downloads/file_upload.pl into the /var/www/cgi-bin/ directory.

I then point my browser to myIpAddress/cgi-bin/file_upload.pl and get a "internal server error ... The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to..."

I then check the error log to find this:

```
[Sun Nov 27 19:59:02 2011] [error] [client ***] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/file_upload.pl' failed
[Sun Nov 27 19:59:02 2011] [error] [client ***] Premature end of script headers: file_upload.pl
[Sun Nov 27 19:59:02 2011] [error] [client ***] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have SELinux enabled, turn on CGI with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi on
```

This assumes that the script is uploaded correctly. Perl scripts don't run too well if they are either saved in a DOS format or are uploaded via binary mode via ftp. If you didn't copy the file via ftp (but instead scp or sftp), convert the file with:

```
dos2unix file_upload.pl
```

Comment: As it turns out, the problem had something to do with the text not being in the right format. And, I have been uploading with sftp. For the benefit of others, Something must have happened when I downloaded the script to my windows machine. Simnply copying it over to a new .pl file in Notepad++ (an IDE) seems to have fixed it... the exact same file! Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Sure. BTW, sftp is fine. So most likely it is the file not being in the correct text format.

Answer (score 0):

This to me sounds like you might not have `perl` installed on your machine, or that it might be at a path different than `/usr/bin/perl`. Try typing `/usr/bin/perl -v` at a command line to comfirm that perl is in fact installed.

It's also possible that you're missing execute permissions on `/var/www/cgi-bin/file_upload.pl`.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the first suggestion: I typed usr/bin/perl -v and received "No such file or directory". However, I should say that I have a SOAP .pl files running in the same cgi-bin directory and that this SOAP file is regularly called by a SOAP client with "myIpAddress/cgi-bin/scriptName.pl" and it has been working fine for a few months.  Regarding the second suggestion, I am not sure if this is pertinent, but I did run chmod +x file_upload.pl and the command line made no complaints when I ran it.

Comment: Scratch that first half of my previous reply. I just ran /usr/bin/perl -v and it shows perl v5.8.8 is running. (I made an error by leaving out the first "/".)